# How to use BSON in .Net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.0, bson

I would like to use BSON in my self-host Web API. I'am using .Net Core 2.0 and autofac. In every each tutorial I see that I need add `BsonMediaTypeFormatter` to formatters, but I don't have WebApiConfig.cs with HttpConfiguration. In my Web API I have only startup.cs and program.cs.

In startup.cs I have two methods:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
```

How can I set BSON formatter?

Comment: Do you have a reason to prefer BSON instead JSON?

Comment: Yes "For serializing binary data, such as an image file, BSON is smaller than JSON, because the binary data is not base64-encoded."

Comment: Another reason is to send a BSON object to Mongo - if you send JSON object from .NET to Mongo then dates will be saved as strings (because of ISO formatting) and then can't query date differences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc()
            .AddBsonSerializerFormatters();
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont have AddBsonSerializerFormatters method. I need add reference or get nuget?

Comment: You'll need [WebApiContrib.Core.Formatter.Bson](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebApiContrib.Core.Formatter.Bson/).

Comment: Ok I see this method, have you maby example how to use bson in application?

Comment: you can send the raw BSON bytes in the HTTP  POST.

Comment: But postman have only Json (application/json). I would like have in Content-Type application/bson it is possible?

Comment: I have base64 string I try to send it by HTTP POST but not working. I need send it by Text? JSON? and with "0x"?

Comment: you can send it as a metadata (header content) if it's not a large data or you can send as a stream or you can convert it to JSON and send if that overhead is justifiable.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/bson-support-in-web-api-21 might help

Comment: There is no AddMvc() in a web api project, is this a pre .Net5 example?